# Which approach to use for KVC?

Tags: objective-c

Which way is better to use for Key Value Coding? Lets assume that **MyController** class have variable **myVariable**. Could some one write opinion which is good which is bad and why.

## 1.

```
// Method in the MyController class.
- (NSString*)myVariableKVC {
    return NSStringFromSelector(@selector(myVariable));
}

[myController addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:[myController myVariableKVC]
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:nil];
```

## 2.

```
[myController addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"myVariable"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:nil];
```

From my point of view first part is more better. We do not have hard coded strings and when we will do rename using **Refactor -> Rename...** then it will be renamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a waring named `-Wundeclared-selector` (Xcode name: "Undeclared Selector", Xcode build setting: `GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR`) enabled, the first way will give you some warning from the compiler if you change the name of the selector (to something that isn't declared anywhere as a selector) and as you point out, this marginally reduces hard-coded/"magic" strings. I wouldn't bother having a separate method for it though, I just do this:

```
[myController addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(myVariable))
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:nil];
```

This warning is **not** on by default in the Xcode project templates I looked at, so if you want this check, you'll need to manually turn on that warning for your project.

Absent that warning, there's no difference, except that the first method incurs another function call (and ObjC message send in the case of having an ObjC method that returns the selector as appears in the question). I feel like this warning used to be on by default, but things change, I guess.

Comment: This is actually incorrect.  The compiler will not produce a warning if there's a typo in the selector name.  It ends up being no different than using a hardcoded magic string.

Comment: Oh, hey, you're right. I feel like it used to give "unknown selector" warnings... maybe I'm confused. Oh well. Edited for posterity.

Comment: If you have strict compiler warnings on (which you should), you will get an error if that selector doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: Just now, I've turned on "Pedantic Warnings" and "Strict Selector Matching" and I still don't get a warning from `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(ajshjkhgwle));`

Comment: You have to turn on a waring named `-Wundeclared-selector` (Xcode name: "Undeclared Selector", Xcode build setting: `GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR`).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Thanks! I was hoping I wasn't crazy!