# Why use NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived)) in for forKeyPath in addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context in AFNetworking?

Tags: afnetworking, key-value-observing

In AFNetworking source code AFURLSessionManager.m，

```
(NSURLSessionTask *)task
[task addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived))
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:NULL];
```

Why use "NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived))" instead of @"countOfBytesReceived".

Comment: [Which approach to use for KVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15023832/4244136)

Answer (score 3):

`NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived))` is strictly better because any typo or misspelling will be caught at compile time as long as you have the "Undeclared Selector" warning turned on in Xcode. If you instead you incorrectly use, for example, `@"countOfByteReceived"` everything will compile fine but your code will fail to work as desired at run time. The `NSStringFromSelector` form will also let the editor help you with code completion.